# How to sort the inner array from a multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm getting a multidimensional array named `$user_alerts` generated from the SQL query. For your reference I'm printing the array here:

```
Array
(
    [154472] => Array
        (
            [3829802] => Array
                (
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

            [3830078] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34429] => 34429
                )

            [3829803] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154554] => Array
        (
            [3831407] => Array
                (
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34442] => 34442
                )

            [3831408] => Array
                (
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                )

        )

    [154551] => Array
        (
            [3831329] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34429] => 34429
                )

        )

    [154477] => Array
        (
            [3830046] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

            [3829564] => Array
                (
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154474] => Array
        (
            [3829402] => Array
                (
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154473] => Array
        (
            [3829377] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154541] => Array
        (
            [3831211] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34429] => 34429
                )

        )

    [154514] => Array
        (
            [3830597] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154513] => Array
        (
            [3830557] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

        )

    [154493] => Array
        (
            [3830072] => Array
                (
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34438] => 34438
                    [34443] => 34443
                )

            [3829611] => Array
                (
                    [34429] => 34429
                )

        )

    [154491] => Array
        (
            [3829998] => Array
                (
                    [34429] => 34429
                    [34443] => 34443
                    [34442] => 34442
                    [34438] => 34438
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to sort the internal array in ascending order. 
The sample internal array which needs to be sorted is as follows(the first inner array element).

```
 [3829802] => Array
                    (
                        [34438] => 34438
                        [34442] => 34442
                        [34429] => 34429
                        [34443] => 34443
                    )
```

Actually I want to sort all such inner arrays. I tried lot of tricks but nothing gave me the desired result. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried lot of tricks" Yes? Which ones? Just looping over the arrays and sort their children is not valid solution for you?

Comment: Can you modify the query with an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Sorting arrays is a trivial task, but I completely agree with @DevlshOne in the regard that instead of solving a problem, you should try and avoid making one by ordering the data in your query

Comment: Oder by does not works for me becuase array is not just coming from DB. we are inserting another array into that

Answer (score 3):

When you generate the array is the best time to sort it. When you build up the arrays simply call `ksort($array)`.

If for whatever reason that's not feasible or possible you can just loop over the arrays and sort:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    foreach($value as $innerKey => $inner){
        ksort($inner);
        $array[$key][$innerKey] = $inner;
    }
}
```